# NSOutputStream: delete existing file if stream is incomplete?

Tags: ios, xcode, file, delete-file, nsoutputstream

I'm using NSUrlConnection and NSOutputStream to write the file. But when the file doesn't exist or there is an error while downloading I want to be able to remove the incomplete downloaded file.

Is there a operation for this? Because otherwise I get a file with 0 bytes content...

Answer (score 0):

Handling Stream Errors like this:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

NSLog(@"stream:handleEvent: is invoked...");
switch(eventCode) {

    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

    {
       //give alert about error
       // remove current incomplete download data here
       break;
    }

    // continued ....

   }

 }
```

Comment: Which delegate do I need for this method?

Comment: add NSStreamDelegate in your interface. Plus set yourNSOutputStreamobject delegate= self

Comment: I implemented it so far, but how can I delete the incomplete downloaded 0-byte file?

Comment: still no solution for this issue, has anyone an idea please?!